# how can use EXISTS command of sqlite in flutter

Tags: flutter

i want know how to use EXISTS operator in both dbhelper and main dart file .

i am tried below code but its not working.

```
Future<List<Client>> check(String Name) async {
    final db = await database;
    var res = await db.rawQuery("EXISTS SELECT * FROM Client WHERE uname =?)");
    List<Client> list = res.isNotEmpty ? res.map((c) => Client.fromMap(c)).toList() : [null];
    return list;
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: do you know the EXISTS syntax?

Answer (score 0):

In you question, you only have one table, you do not need keyword EXISTS. 
For EXISTS syntax, you can reference http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-exists/ 
You can test your sql in https://sqliteonline.com/

```
SELECT * FROM demo WHERE name = 'SQL'
```

[image]